# make text at different side in li tag of html

Tags: html, html-lists

i want to make a page like this:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aTcIiLRrrxNX_ELgpX9ZoacjlWRia4RO

I did following things to do but it is not happening exactly as of the the image above:

```html
<ul>
<li class="que1">नाम&emsp;&emsp;:&nbsp;सिद्धिचरण श्रेष्ठ</li>
<li style="list-style: none;">जन्मस्थान &emsp;&emsp;:&nbsp;ओखलढुङ्गा जिल्लाको ओखलढुङ्गा बजार </li>
<li style="list-style: none;"> जन्ममिति&emsp;&emsp;:&nbsp;वि.सं. १९६९ जेठ ९ गते </li>
<li style="list-style: none;">मातापिता &emsp;&emsp;:&nbsp;नीरकुमारी श्रेष्ठ र विष्णुचरण श्रेष्ठ </li>
<li style="list-style: none;">साहित्यिक यात्रा&emsp;&emsp;:&nbsp;वि.सं. १९९० मा गोरखापत्रमा 'भुइँचालो'कविता प्रकाशित</li>
<li style="list-style: none;">योगदान&emsp;&emsp;:&nbsp;शारदा र गोरखापत्र पत्रिकाका सम्पादक र वि.सं. २०१४ मा नेपाल प्रज्ञा प्रतिष्ठानका सदस्य</li>
                        <li style="list-style: none;">कृतिहरू&emsp;&emsp;:&nbsp;खण्डकाव्यमा उर्वशी, ज्यानमारा शैल, मङ्गलमान, आँसु कविता सङ्ग्रहहरूमा कोपिला, मेरो प्रतिबिम्ब, कुहिरो र घाम, बाँचिरहेको आवाज, तिरमिर तारा, सिद्धिचरणका प्रतिनिधि कविता</li>
                        </ul>
```

Comment: Why not use table instead of a list ?

Comment: @SaravananKandasamy i was also thinking for that if i don't get any solution. btw, can we hide the border of table?

Comment: i have put the html in answer try it , if you are getting borders then just css it 
table, th, td {
  border: none;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```css
li{
 width: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
 list-style: none;
}
span.left-text{
 width: 20%;
 float: left;
}
span.content-text{
 width: calc(80% - 30px);
 float: left;
}
span.text-center{
 padding: 0px 10px;
 float: left;
}
```

```html
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span class="left-text">नाम</span>
      <span class="text-center">:</span>
      <span class="content-text">सिद्धिचरण श्रेष्ठ</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span  class="left-text">जन्मस्थान</span>
      <span class="text-center">:</span>  
      <span class="content-text">खण्डकाव्यमा उर्वशी, ज्यानमारा शैल, मङ्गलमान, आँसु कविता सङ्ग्रहहरूमा कोपिला, मेरो प्रतिबिम्ब, कुहिरो र घाम, बाँचिरहेको आवाज, तिरमिर तारा, सिद्धिचरणका प्रतिनिधि कविता</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
.name:after{
  content: ':';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>

<body>
<div>
  <div class="row w-100">
    <div class="col-3 name">
      नाम
    </div>
    <div class="col-9">
      सिद्धिचरण श्रेष्ठ
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row w-100">
    <div class="col-3 name">
      जन्मस्थान 
    </div>
    <div class="col-9">
      ओखलढुङ्गा जिल्लाको ओखलढुङ्गा बजार 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row w-100">
    <div class="col-3 name">
      जन्ममिति
    </div>
    <div class="col-9">
      वि.सं. १९६९ जेठ ९ गते
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row w-100">
    <div class="col-3 name">
     मातापिता
    </div>
    <div class="col-9">
      नीरकुमारी श्रेष्ठ र विष्णुचरण श्रेष्ठ
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row w-100">
    <div class="col-3 name">
      साहित्यिक यात्रा
    </div>
    <div class="col-9">
      वि.सं. १९९० मा गोरखापत्रमा 'भुइँचालो'कविता प्रकाशित
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row w-100">
    <div class="col-3 name">
      योगदान
    </div>
    <div class="col-9">
      शारदा र गोरखापत्र पत्रिकाका सम्पादक र वि.सं. २०१४ मा नेपाल प्रज्ञा प्रतिष्ठानका सदस्य
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row w-100">
    <div class="col-3 name">
     कृतिहरू
    </div>
    <div class="col-9">
      खण्डकाव्यमा उर्वशी, ज्यानमारा शैल, मङ्गलमान, आँसु कविता सङ्ग्रहहरूमा कोपिला, मेरो प्रतिबिम्ब, कुहिरो र घाम, बाँचिरहेको आवाज, तिरमिर तारा, सिद्धिचरणका प्रतिनिधि कविता
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: i want to make this completly offline, isn't there any solution?

Comment: You can download css and js files of this CDNs. @Dibas

Comment: please can you elaborate more, I've no idea in this, how can i download that?

Comment: can't we do it except js and bootstrap?

Comment: This links are for bootstrap4. This all CDN's are require for bootstrap 4. @Dibas

Comment: You can download from this website: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/download/ @Dibas

Answer (score 1):

--
P.S Please excuses if there are mistake in words, i don't know the language just copy pasted.

```html
<table>

  <tr>
    <td>नाम</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>सिद्धिचरण श्रेष्ठ</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>जन्मस्थान</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>ओखलढुङ्गा जिल्लाको ओखलढुङ्गा बजार</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>जन्ममिति</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td> वि.सं. १९६९ जेठ ९ गते </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>मातापिता</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>नीरकुमारी श्रेष्ठ र विष्णुचरण श्रेष्ठ </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>साहित्यिक यात्रा</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>वि.सं. १९९० मा गोरखापत्रमा 'भुइँचालो'कविता प्रकाशित</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>योगदान</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>शारदा र गोरखापत्र पत्रिकाका सम्पादक र वि.सं. २०१४ मा नेपाल प्रज्ञा प्रतिष्ठानका सदस्य</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>कृतिहरू</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>खण्डकाव्यमा उर्वशी, ज्यानमारा शैल, मङ्गलमान, आँसु कविता सङ्ग्रहहरूमा कोपिला, मेरो प्रतिबिम्ब, कुहिरो र घाम, बाँचिरहेको आवाज, तिरमिर तारा, सिद्धिचरणका प्रतिनिधि कविता</td>
  </tr>


</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the HTML

```
    <ul>
        <li class="que1">
            <div class="title"> नाम </div>
            <div class="desc"> : सिद्धिचरण श्रेष्ठ</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="title"> जन्मस्थान </div>
            <div class="desc"> : ओखलढुङ्गा जिल्लाको ओखलढुङ्गा बजार </div>
        </li>

        <li>
            <div class="title">जन्ममिति </div>
            <div class="desc"> : वि.सं. १९६९ जेठ ९ गते </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="title"> मातापिता </div>
            <div class="desc"> : नीरकुमारी श्रेष्ठ र विष्णुचरण श्रेष्ठ </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="title">साहित्यिक यात्रा </div>
            <div class="desc"> : वि.सं. १९९० मा गोरखापत्रमा 'भुइँचालो'कविता
                प्रकाशित</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="title"> योगदान </div>
            <div class="desc"> : शारदा र गोरखापत्र पत्रिकाका सम्पादक र वि.सं. २०१४ मा
                नेपाल प्रज्ञा प्रतिष्ठानका सदस्य</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="title"> कृतिहरू </div>
            <div class="desc"> : खण्डकाव्यमा उर्वशी, ज्यानमारा शैल, मङ्गलमान, आँसु
                कविता
                सङ्ग्रहहरूमा कोपिला, मेरो प्रतिबिम्ब, कुहिरो र घाम, बाँचिरहेको आवाज, तिरमिर तारा, सिद्धिचरणका प्रतिनि
                कविता
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

and this is the CSS

```
ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
}

ul li .title {
    max-width: 15%;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 15%;
    flex: 0 0 15%;
}

ul li .desc {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```